# Can't restore Mac from Timemachine on external drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, ssd, external-disk

I am doing time machine backups of my macbook on an encrypted external drive. That drive has 2TB capacity.

#### Thats the backup drive

[image]

#### Diskutil list

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         702.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                298.2 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +702.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.3 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     570.4 GB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.6 MB    disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Backup - Macbook Pro... 2.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3

/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Backup - Macbook Pr... +2.0 TB     disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                 28941B6F-CE5A-4B0E-8B4E-38AE62256998
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

So doing time machine backups is just fine. Full system recovery is not.

#### <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> Boot

[image]

#### Time Machine Backup

[image]
[image]

#### `tmutil listbackups`

```
/Volumes/Backup - Macbook Pro 16'' 2020/Backups.backupdb/.nomad5.osx.16/2021-04-25-122101
/Volumes/Backup - Macbook Pro 16'' 2020/Backups.backupdb/.nomad5.osx.16/2021-04-27-083912
```

#### Additional info

- There is also a bootcamp partition existing on the internal drive
- I have tried the same with BigSur on another macbook with the same SSD. And it shows the backups from the external drive. So no problem with the drive

## The Problem / Restoring my 16x macbook

When I try to restore the full system on my 16 macbook from the time machine backup, it's not available for me. When start into the recovery mode (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>) and unlock the backup drive, I don't see any options to do a full system recovery.

The only rollback option I see is, when I unlock my "Macintosh HD", which is not the external drive. But its always the date I have created the backup. But only one.

I am confused:

Does this mean all of my backups have been just a waste of time? How can I properly back up my **whole** mac for the case of emergency?

Comment: You need to tell us the version of macOS on both MBP.  The output of Disk Utility (with Show All Devices enabled) and/or Terminal command `diskutil list` would help.  You need to describe what you are doing a bit more clearly - e.g. which MBP as you using in the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs.

Comment: @Gilby thanks for your feedback. I have updated the question, is this clearer now?

Comment: That is now clearer. I don't know for sure, but suspect that your problem arises from 2 encrypted backups to one HDD particularly as they are for different major versions of macOS. And what version created each of the two Boot OS X partitions - I don't know. Possible ways forward: 1) Create bootable install of 10.14.6 (on 16GB flash drive), boot from it and see if it can use the 16x partition; 2) create a running macOS 10.14.6 on an external disk (SSD, HDD or even 32GB flash drive) that should see both partitions.

Comment: @Gilby I have massively simplified the question. Now the full external drive is for the backups of one mac only. Still not working as intended. Any further suggestions

Comment: What return the terminal command : `tmutil listbackups`

Comment: @Jean_JD updated the question with the requested info

Comment: If you open Options on TM panel, what is excluded?

Comment: @Jean_JD updated the question again

Comment: Ok. No problem for this. Have you try a save without encrypted mode?

Comment: You mean the timemachine backup on a non encrypted drive?

Comment: Yes. It's only for a test.

Comment: @Jean_JD will let it run over night and get back to you tomorrow

Comment: @Jean_JD just did a fresh backup on an non-encrypted external drive. Identical results

Comment: Damned. ;-) You have a T2 Mac could you see this : https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT208198 ?

Comment: Which setting should I try? Sacure boot or external boot?

Comment: @Jean_JD unfortunately disabling everything does not yield a different result

Comment: If your system is Big Sur your Time Machine volume is formated APFS?

Comment: No, the time machine backup drive is "MacOS Extended (journeled)" If i try to let it an APFS it will be converted as soon as i want to start the backup via time machine

Comment: Can you restore individual item from this way  : https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/mac-help/mh11422/10.15/mac/10.15 ?

Comment: @Jean_JD Yes, i can restore that way. Apple support also told me that i can backup everything with the "migration assistant" after a fresh install. I am still wondering whats wrong with this approach

Comment: Have you try to boot on the TM Disk (hold alt at boot) and if it's work, can you restore by this way?

Comment: @Jean_JD nope, i cannot select it for booting